# WebApplicationException weirdness

Tags: jersey

I've extended WebApplicationException with an UnauthorizedException:

```
public class UnauthorizedException extends WebApplicationException {
```

My REST classes extend a base class that implements the authCheck, a subclass method:

```
try{
  authCheck();
  RecordingList recordings = CODIRecording.getRecordings(type, timeframe);
  return Response.ok().entity(recordings).build();
}catch(WebApplicationException e){
  throw e; // Results in 500
  throw new UnauthorizedException(); // Results in 401
}
```

When the authCheck fails it throws UnauthorizedException. If the subclass method doesn't have the catch/try (the exception just propagates out from authCheck) or if it re-throws the exception the client receives a 500.

If the method's catch throws a *NEW* UnauthorizedException the client receives a 401 as expected.

Is this "normal" behavior? It seems odd.

Comment: While I'm begging... anyone know of a way for an AspectJ @Before aspect to get access to the Jersey injected (@Context) header info? I'd like to move authCheck out of the method and into an aspect.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that what you are actually catching there is not UnauthorizedException, but some other WebApplicationException. Did you try debugger? Or simply do e.printStackTrace() in the catch clause to be sure.

Comment: That's the odd thing, the catch is catching an UnauthorizedException:
UnauthorizedException
 at AuthorizationAspect.authCheck(AuthorizationAspect.java:21)

Jersey is behaving like it's getting a non-WebApplicationException and wrapping it as a 500.

Comment: Each WebApplicationException embeds a response. The UnauthorizedException you are catching has probably a different response set then the UnauthorizedException you are throwing. Call e.getResponse().getStatus() see if it really returns 401. Also see what kind of entity it has - maybe the UnauthorizedException you are catching has the status code set to 500 or contains an entity that Jersey fails to write to the stream and returns 500 in the end. Or the content type of the response is not set properly - basically inspect the e.getResponse() value and see if it looks OK.

Comment: Btw, if you know you are definitely catching and re-throwing UnauthorizedException and not just any arbitrary WebApplicationException, why don't you change the catch clause to catch (UnauthorizedException e)?

Comment: It's returning a 401. Another team member slipped a buggy exception mapper into the build, co-pilot error. Thanks for the help.